not able to quit django server on windows pc
I installed Django just 10 minutes back on my Windows 11 PC and I was trying out this command from a tutorial in a virtual environment i created using anaconda
python manage.py runserver and this is what i got
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
June 03, 2024 - 16:21:24
Django version 4.2.13, using settings 'chaiaurDjango.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

now my keyboard doesn't have the break key and I am trying both ctrl+c and ctrl +z but the server wont quit, and neither the command prompt is taking any inputs its just stuck there whatever I type doesn't show on the command prompt, How do i quit the server

You normally can remap keys such that there is a break key somewhere.

You can also kill the process in the task manager, but that is of course less convenient.

A robust way to end the process is with the Task manager [wiki], you can open this by hitting Ctrl + Alt + Delete, search the process that is running the Django server, and kill the task.
But this is of course cumbersome to do thi each time. Most systems allow to remap keys [Microsoft-learning-center]: use a different key that you map to Break, or use an (external) keyboard with a Break key.
